How would this venting mobile app look like?
I recently purchased domain "ItPissesMeOff.com" and the purpose is to create a mobile app with funny content where users can simply type in and publish what Pisses Them Off.
For example, the user can type a title and an option short description. So for example:
Title: It Pisses Me Off when someone sneezes without covering his mouth.
Description: and then cleans his hands in his shirt! Disgusting
Then other users contribute to this thread, by typing comments related to the main thread.
My thinking was to display the title, the description, and the 5 most popular comments - then show the next thread. But I'm not sure how I can do that without making the mobile app look corny.
Are there any mobile apps that do something similar? The purpose is primarily to make people laugh by typing in what bothers them.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about any UX problem

How does it look now (please share the design)? Why does it look corny? Are you concerned about a particular design problem (please share) or just interested in design examples (this is not the site for such question)?

@Danielillo: It's about creating an efficient UX based on the app's purpose.

@jazZRo: I haven't created a design because I don't know what UX to use.
